# How to make bottle server HTTPS python

Tags: python-3.x, https, cherrypy, bottle

I'm using Bottle as my webservice. Currently, its running on bottle's default wsgi server and handles HTTP requests. I want to encrypt my webservice and handle HTTPS requests. Can someone suggest a method for this. I tried running on cherrypy server, but the latest version is not supporting the pyOpenSSLAdapter.

Answer (score 9):

As you know bottle also supports Gunicorn. You can find SSL information at

- https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=ssl#ssl

**Code example**

```
import bottle
from bottle import Bottle

BASE = Bottle()


@BASE.route('/', ['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Index'


bottle.run(
    app=BASE, 
    host='0.0.0.0',
    port='8888',
    server='gunicorn',
    reloader=1,
    debug=1,
    keyfile='key.pem',
    certfile='cert.pem'
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried on Windows, but after `pip install gunicorn` I still had: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'` and fcntl seems unavailable on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228395/error-no-module-named-fcntl.

Comment: Working on Linux, thanks! What are the main `gunicorn` advantages? Does it automatically start many processes or threads? Or is it mono-threaded, like wsgirefserver (IIRC)?

Comment: Yes it can, you can use gevent, tornado, eventlet .et.c . 
See https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html

Comment: OK I'll look at that! What would you recommend @EM28? Bottle + gunicorn (+ gevent or tornado or not necessarily?) + nginx or apache ? Or would you totally avoid apache/nginx? I know there are many documented options, but I was curious which one you use, so I'll look at this precisely.

Comment: You can leave out Nginx if your only expecting traffic from identified parties. However, if you are expecting public traffic, Nginx will be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @EM28. Last question: we use bottle for the app itself, gunicorn as web server, but what is the main role of the gevent additional layer? i.e. why not bottle + gunicorn alone?

Comment: Study the following:
(1) https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html
(2) https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html#async-workers

Answer (score 4):

Quick way of achieving https through nginx reverse proxy:-

```
apt install nginx
```

Edit /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:-

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server; #listen on port 80
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com; #edit 'yourdomain' with your domain name
  root /var/www/html/; #edit to match wherever your bottle-py root folder is

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; 
    #assuming configuration of bottle-py run() command is 127.0.0.1:8080
  }
}
```

HTTPS with certbot:-

Login to your domain name provider for 'yourdomain.com' and point 'A-records' to point to your server IP.

```
apt install certbot python-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Follow the on terminal instructions for certbot. Now bottle-py is served with https by a nginx reverse proxy.

Check https://yourdomain.com and confirm https valid certificate installation.

This is a quick way of doing it. Read more at nginx and certbot documentation.

Comment: For ubuntu 20.04 `apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx` [refLink](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-install-the-lets-encrypt-certificate-using-certbot-in-ubuntu-20-04/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your WSGI server (not WsgiRef certainly) behind a reverse-proxy with https support. Nginx is the most common choice.

Comment: sorry it is running on wsgi server only. But I don't know how to implement ssl on this

Comment: Like it or not, but this is how things are done in real-life deployments. Not to mention that you need to serve your static files as well.