# Error: No module named 'fcntl'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, module, compiler-errors

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aaaa/Desktop/ttttttt.py", line 5, in <module>
   import reload
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\reload.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sys, time, re, os, signal, fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

So I did a pip install, which also gets an error.

```
    C:\Users\aaaa>pip install fcntl
    Collecting fcntl
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fcntl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for fcntl
```

Search results cPython, hacking, routing and many other words are coming out.

It's a tough answer for beginners, so I want to get a more detailed solution.

How should I solve it?

```
#py3
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import sys
import reload
import re
import fcntl
import os
import signal
```

Comment: What did you do to get it working on Windows?

Answer (score 62):

The `fcntl` module is not available on Windows. The functionality it exposes does not exist on that platform.

If you're trying to lock a file, there are some other Python modules available which provide that functionality. One I've seen referenced in other answers is [`portalocker`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/portalocker).

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have downloaded the above, but now I am having trouble figuring out how to use it.

Comment: Do I understand it properly that I cannot do a non-blocking read from a pipe on Windows in this "language"?

Comment: @User149341 And after what we have to do?

Comment: Well like the others, this module is not available on Windows, but how can that mentioned package help?

Answer (score 37):

I got the same error when trying to run my flask app using gunicorn.

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 predict:app
```

The issue is that 'fcntl' is not available on windows. The alternative that can be used, as suggested by Alexey Grigorov in Ml bookcamp, is the 'waitress' package.

```
pip install waitress
```

Then write in the command prompt the following command.

```
waitress-serve --listen=127.0.0.1:5000 predict:app
```

For those still looking for the answer.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 thanks

Answer (score 6):

"gunicorn" is not intended for use on Windows. To run the program, consider using Docker or a virtual machine (VM).

For further insights and discussions regarding the compatibility issues with Windows, you can refer to the GitHub discussions:

- [Add Windows support](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524)
- [No module named 'fcntl'(issue closed)](https://github.com/doccano/doccano/issues/1414)

*Again note `gunicorn` is not intended for Windows.*

**For Django project deployment(similar is procedure if you want to use for deployment in other python framework)**

#### Running on Windows

If you're using Windows, you can use **Waitress** as an alternative to Gunicorn.

1. Create a `server.py` file with the following content:

```py
from waitress import serve
from yourdjangoproject.wsgi import application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, port='8000')
```

2. Run the server using the command:

```
python server.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I got some info from this website  https://pypi.org/project/micropython-fcntl/#files and installed as follows which solved the problem:

```
pip install micropython-fcntl
```

Comment: `ERROR: File "setup.py" or "setup.cfg" not found for legacy project micropython-fcntl from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/65/f233834bc23621c1a8da644bd1d70cbe5c344bd2dd2b9d424f1f116363ec/micropython-fcntl-0.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=6ce976b79c16084485894e4284c54263c0cc775cf6b4a6fd3bf1d83f29ddf6a1.` :(

Comment: this is not working as @cactuschibre said :(

Comment: `ERROR: micropython-fcntl from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/65/f233834bc23621c1a8da644bd1d70cbe5c344bd2dd2b9d424f1f116363ec/micropython-fcntl-0.0.4.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`

Comment: I am getting the same error as above :(

Answer (score -4):

What you can do is install importlib with the usual:

```
pip install importlib
```

From there use the following:

```
from importlib import reload
```

Note that you will need to load your imports as 'modules':

```
from petshop import parrot as parrot
```

Comment: I'm not following how this answer relates to the question. `importlib.reload()` can be used to reload a module. The user's question is related to "`fcntl` doesn't exist on windows". How do you reload a module that isn't even isntalled because it doesn't exist?

Comment: Besides answering the wrong question, `importlib` needs no pip install in anything released in the last decade (this answer was already obsolete when posted).