# What is the right method to install KoboToolbox on a local by using Docker on my computer?

Tags: python, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've downloaded *KoboToolbox* from the links below and followed the installation instructions:

- https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobo-install
- https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobo-docker.

The steps are not clear to me and the `python run.py` command is not working. Here is the error which occured:

```sh
$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 9, in <module>
    from helpers.command import Command
  File "C:\users\eng-mohammed\Desktop\kobo\kobo-install\helpers\command.py", line 9, in <module>
    from helpers.config import Config
  File "C:\users\eng-mohammed\Desktop\kobo\kobo-install\helpers\config.py", line 15, in <module>
    from helpers.network import Network
  File "C:\users\eng-mohammed\Desktop\kobo\kobo-install\helpers\network.py", line 5, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
".
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a windows OS, I think this is the issue, see  [Error: No module named 'fcntl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228395/error-no-module-named-fcntl)

[Kobo-install](https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobo-install) specifies in its [requirements](https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobo-install#requirements) Linux/macOS as OS