# Gradio cannot install

Tags: python, installation, pip, gradio

I tried several ways to install gradio. But it gives this error every time. I can't install it. What could be the solution?

```
C:\Users\ugurn>pip install gradio
Collecting gradio
  Using cached gradio-3.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (13.8 MB)
Collecting python-multipart
  Using cached python-multipart-0.0.5.tar.gz (32 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [34 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z61k1lxd\python-multipart_8b04b9f47ece46d0a012ed3b3c3183cb\setup.py", line 19, in <module>
          setup(name='python-multipart',
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 147, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 475, in __init__
          _Distribution.__init__(
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 283, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 898, in finalize_options
          for ep in sorted(loaded, key=by_order):
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 897, in <lambda>
          loaded = map(lambda e: e.load(), filtered)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 171, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\py2app\build_app.py", line 37, in <module>
          from py2app.create_appbundle import create_appbundle
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\py2app\create_appbundle.py", line 9, in <module>
          from py2app.util import make_exec, makedirs, mergecopy, mergetree, skipscm
        File "C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\py2app\util.py", line 5, in <module>
          import fcntl
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I want to install Gradio without any problem

Comment: See here for a maybe possible reason (fcntl not available in Windows): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228395/ddg#45228507 ( the error message you are getting says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to `gradio`. You have installed `py2app` on your Windows but https://pypi.org/project/py2app/ is only for Mac OS X. Uninstall `py2app`:

```
pip uninstall -y py2app
```

or remove the directory `C:\Users\ugurn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\py2app`

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed Gradio.